# How do I get div to work right in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am adding  sections to our website and all but one of them are working the way I want: i.e. no margin between sections.

I'm not able to get this one page's  sections to have no margin between sections; they have extra space beneath.  I have went over the code with a fine tooth comb and cannot find the error.

I am first including the code of a sample page that works correctly:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="windows-1252">

  <style media="screen" type="text/css">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
    
    body {
      background: fuchsia;
      color: purple;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Georgia;
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
      clear: left;
    }
    
    option {
      background: yellow;
      color: purple;
    }
    
    table {
      background: yellow;
    }
    
    caption {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .copyright {
      color: white;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .logo {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 30%;
      padding-left: 280px
    }
    
    .cta {
      background: Red;
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Georgia;
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      padding: 5 5 5 5px;
      clear: left;
    }
    
    .text {
      background: MediumSpringGreen;
      color: black;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Georgia;
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      padding: 5 5 5 5px;
      clear: left;
    }
  }
  /*]]>*/
  </style>
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
  <title>Vegan and Raw Vegan Books for Sale</title>
  <meta content="Choose poetry ebooks praising the benefits of veganism and vegetarian cuisine" name="description" />
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo"><img alt="black female entrepreneurs 2018 on soapbox" height="345" src="IMG_8292.JPG" width="240" /></div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Choose Vegan Books</h1>Veganism kicks butt! Veganism kicks arse! Veganism kicks ass! These vegan poetry books call you to find fulfillment through veganism.
    <h2>Hurray for Raw Foods and Raw Veganism: 40 Poems</h2>When you combine two great things, veganism and the raw food diet, you create something even greater yet: raw veganism. Raw veganism can take the world by storm. Other books focus on explaining raw
    veganism and providing raw vegan recipes; this book focuses on celebrating raw veganism through poetry.
    <p></p>42 pages; 40 poems.
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="cta"><img alt="vegan lifestyle book" height="230" src="Raw Veganism 1600 x 2300.jpg" width="160" />
    <p></p><a href="https://gum.co/mbpTD">Choose Hurray for Raw Foods and Raw Veganism: 40 Poems</a>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Let's Use Free Speech to Praise the Vegan Way</h2>Some consider veganism tough; I consider it doable; Some consider veganism unsound; I consider it justified; Some consider veganism foolish; I consider it wise; And you will feel the same; After reading
    this poetry chapbook.
    <p></p>Do you want to go vegan yet need some encouragement? Have you already gone vegan and want to celebrate veganism? In either case, this book will give you what you need.
    <p></p>26 pages; 25 poems.
    <p></p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="cta"> <img alt="veganism pros" height="230" src="Vegan 1600 x 2300.jpg" width="160" />
    <p></p><a href="https://gum.co/chCeB">Choose Let's Use Free Speech to Praise the Vegan Way</a></div>
  <div class="copyright">
    <p></p>&copy2017-2021 Free Press Media Press Inc.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the code that is not working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

  <style media="screen" type="text/css">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
    
    body {
      background: fuchsia;
      color: purple;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Georgia;
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
      clear: left;
    }
    
    option {
      background: yellow;
      color: purple;
    }
    
    table {
      background: yellow;
    }
    
    caption {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .copyright {
      color: white;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .logo {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 30%;
      padding-left: 280px
    }
    
    .cta {
      background: Red;
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Georgia;
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      padding: 5 5 5 5px;
      clear: left;
    }
    
    .text {
      background: MediumSpringGreen;
      color: black;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Georgia;
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      padding: 5 5 5 5px;
      clear: left;
    }
  }
  /*]]>*/
  </style>
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
  <title>Best Labor Unions Books for Sale</title>
  <meta content="Chose the best labor unions books promoting unions in texas and discussing labor unions pros and cons" name="description">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo"><img alt="black woman activist" height="345" src="IMG_8292.JPG" width="240" /></div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Choose Union Books</h1>Andrew Bushard's efforts to unionize Accenture has been inspiring people. Andrew Bushard filed a National Labor Relations Board (NLRB) unfair labor charge against his employer Accenture for violating his unionization rights.
    The NLRB agent "found merit" in his charge, so the NLRB prosecuted Accenture. Accenture capitulated and agreed to a settlement, so Andrew won the case. Victory! Andrew Bushard's unionizing success can empower you when you unionize and pursue other
    leadership endeavors.
    <h2>Let's Use Free Speech to Unionize Accenture and Other Companies</h2>Accenture doesn't pay its call center workers enough, so unions should intervene. This work discusses the problems of Accenture type leadership as well as advocates for the political
    and philosophical need for the unionization solution.
    <p></p>
    36 pages. Cover illustration by rifatnaim.</div>
  <div class="cta"><img alt="black female revolutionaries on cover" height="230" src="labor%20unions%20today.jpg" width="160" />
    <p></p> <a href="https://gum.co/gKukG">Choose Let's Use Free Speech to Unionize Accenture and Other Companies</a></div>
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Let's Use Free Speech to Promote Unions at Accenture and Other Places</h2>Since you enjoyed my book <i>Let's Use Free Speech to Unionize Accenture and Other Companies</i>, you will enjoy this one as well. Since writing the first book, lots of things
    have happened and I have developed new insights, so read this book to learn more.
    <p></p>
    28 pages. Cover illustration by rifatnaim.</div>
  <div class="cta"><img alt="radical union book" height="230" src="unions%20labor.jpg" width="160" />
    <p></p><a href="https://gum.co/KrWFn">Choose Let's Use Free Speech to Promote Unions at Accenture and Other Places</a></div>
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Let's Use Free Speech to #UnionizeAccenture and #UnionizeEverywhere</h2>Despite opposition and obstacles, Andrew Bushard has continued to answer his calling to unionize the company of Accenture. Since the publication of his books <em>Let's Use Free Speech to Unionize Accenture and Other Companies</em>    and <em>Let's Use Free Speech to Promote Unions at Accenture and Other Places</em>, he has continued resisting management and he has experienced a paradigm shift realizing all unions are not the same. This work describes his encounters with bad and
    harmful unions, repressive and arrogant management, apathetic and hostile coworkers, and helpful and encouraging Syndicalists.
    <p></p>
    32 pages. Cover illustration by rifatnaim.</div>
  <div class="cta"><img alt="Unions in America" height="230" src="unfair%20labor%20practices%20examples.jpg" width="160" />
    <p></p><a href="https://gum.co/VNsIOZ">Choose Let's Use Free Speech to #UnionizeAccenture and #UnionizeEverywhere</a></div>
  <div class="copyright">
    <p></p>&copy2017-2021 Free Press Media Press Inc.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I did differently in these two codes and how to correct the second one?

Comment: I mean, I see multiple semantic issues in both, improper use of tags, unopened / closed tags, invalid css properties, etc etc. All of which will cause you issues between different browsers and also do you no favors regarding SEO. Are you just wanting your divs to all connect without margins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are experiencing is called "collapsing margins". Example: If there's an `h2` as the first child element inside a div, and the div has no margins, the top margin of the `h2` will "go outside the div" at the top - h1, h2 etc. tags have a default margins in practically all browsers (which is a browser setting). To prevent that, you can define all margins for according elements as zero, like I did below with

```
h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

But of course this also will affect all other h1 and h2 tags, so you might want to use a class instead, or use a selector like `div > h1, div > h2 { margin: 0; }`

```css
body {
  background: fuchsia;
  color: purple;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  clear: left;
}

option {
  background: yellow;
  color: purple;
}

table {
  background: yellow;
}

caption {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.copyright {
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
  padding-left: 280px
}

.cta {
  background: Red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 5 5 5 5px;
  clear: left;
}

.text {
  background: MediumSpringGreen;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 5 5 5 5px;
  clear: left;
}

h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"><img alt="black woman activist" height="345" src="IMG_8292.JPG" width="240" /></div>
<div class="text">
  <h1>Choose Union Books</h1>Andrew Bushard's efforts to unionize Accenture has been inspiring people. Andrew Bushard filed a National Labor Relations Board (NLRB) unfair labor charge against his employer Accenture for violating his unionization rights. The
  NLRB agent "found merit" in his charge, so the NLRB prosecuted Accenture. Accenture capitulated and agreed to a settlement, so Andrew won the case. Victory! Andrew Bushard's unionizing success can empower you when you unionize and pursue other leadership
  endeavors.
  <h2>Let's Use Free Speech to Unionize Accenture and Other Companies</h2>Accenture doesn't pay its call center workers enough, so unions should intervene. This work discusses the problems of Accenture type leadership as well as advocates for the political
  and philosophical need for the unionization solution.
  <p></p>
  36 pages. Cover illustration by rifatnaim.</div>
<div class="cta"><img alt="black female revolutionaries on cover" height="230" src="labor%20unions%20today.jpg" width="160" />
  <p></p> <a href="https://gum.co/gKukG">Choose Let's Use Free Speech to Unionize Accenture and Other Companies</a></div>
<div class="text">
  <h2>Let's Use Free Speech to Promote Unions at Accenture and Other Places</h2>Since you enjoyed my book <i>Let's Use Free Speech to Unionize Accenture and Other Companies</i>, you will enjoy this one as well. Since writing the first book, lots of things
  have happened and I have developed new insights, so read this book to learn more.
  <p></p>
  28 pages. Cover illustration by rifatnaim.</div>
<div class="cta"><img alt="radical union book" height="230" src="unions%20labor.jpg" width="160" />
  <p></p><a href="https://gum.co/KrWFn">Choose Let's Use Free Speech to Promote Unions at Accenture and Other Places</a></div>
<div class="text">
  <h2>Let's Use Free Speech to #UnionizeAccenture and #UnionizeEverywhere</h2>Despite opposition and obstacles, Andrew Bushard has continued to answer his calling to unionize the company of Accenture. Since the publication of his books <em>Let's Use Free Speech to Unionize Accenture and Other Companies</em>  and <em>Let's Use Free Speech to Promote Unions at Accenture and Other Places</em>, he has continued resisting management and he has experienced a paradigm shift realizing all unions are not the same. This work describes his encounters with bad and
  harmful unions, repressive and arrogant management, apathetic and hostile coworkers, and helpful and encouraging Syndicalists.
  <p></p>
  32 pages. Cover illustration by rifatnaim.</div>
<div class="cta"><img alt="Unions in America" height="230" src="unfair%20labor%20practices%20examples.jpg" width="160" />
  <p></p><a href="https://gum.co/VNsIOZ">Choose Let's Use Free Speech to #UnionizeAccenture and #UnionizeEverywhere</a></div>
<div class="copyright">
  <p></p>&copy2017-2021 Free Press Media Press Inc.
</div>
```